# Trying to prove Kaplan-Meier statistic with no censoring reduces to empirical survival function

Tags: self-study, survival, kaplan-meier

I just started taking survival analysis class and I'm stumped on this question.

We need to show that when there are no censored observations, $\hat{S}(t)=\prod_{t_{(i)\le t}}\frac{(n_i-d_i)}{n_i}$ equals to the empirical survival function $S_n(t)=\frac{\# \{ t_{(i)} \ge t \}}n . $

It looks pretty obvious to me but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: This fact is very important to embed survival analysis in "classic" statistics. What do you see when you write down the first few terms of the product?